# Calling AMQ Listener from APIGEE Proxy end point

Tags: jms, apigee, amq

I am creating the APIGEE proxy from APIGEE edge. Its target is a Mule deployed application which has no HTTP listener. It is only triggered by AMQ listener. Is there any way to connect to that deployed application and trigger it from APIGEE proxy?

I have tried browsing all the APIGEE blogs, but I'm unable to get the accurate and actual solution.

Comment: What version of Red Hat AMQ are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about the Mule application, which is just passively expecting incoming messages in an ActiveMQ queue. You need to send a message to that queue from the Apigee Edge proxy. For that I think you need to use a [Java callout policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/samples/cookbook/how-create-java-callout) and do the operation in Java code.